# How do you count the number of results returned from a xsl:for-each loop containing another XQuery function?

Tags: xml, xslt, count, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="count-example.xsl"?>
<musiclist>
<mp3>
    <id>MP1003</id>
    <artist>Frank Sinatra</artist>
    <title>Fly Me To The Moon</title>
    <location path="home/music/sinatra/MP1008.mp3" />
</mp3>
<mp3>
    <id>MP1004</id>
    <artist>Frank Sinatra</artist>
    <title>New York, New York</title>
    <location path="home/music/sinatra/MP1004.mp3" />
</mp3>
<mp3>
    <id>MP1005</id>
    <artist>Frank Sinatra</artist>
    <title>Young At Heart</title>
    <location path="home/music/sinatra/MP1009.mp3" />
</mp3>
</musiclist>
```

and the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="musiclist">
    <xsl:for-each select="mp3">
        <xsl:variable name="idvar" select="id" />
        <xsl:if test="contains(location/@path, $idvar) = 0">
            false
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSL will output False twice because the ID I capture is not in the path attribute in the location element as I would like.

How do I count this output, i.e. output the number 2 as the complete result of this XSL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **xsl:for-each** here, you can use the function **count** to count the number of nodes matching a given criteria

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="musiclist">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(mp3[contains(location/@path, id) = 0])" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expression may be better re-written as `<xsl:value-of select="count(mp3[not(contains(location/@path, id))])" />` though, given that **contains** returns either true or false.

Comment: Yes, in XPath 2.0 comparing a boolean to an integer is not allowed.